# Thread "does not implement" error with CLASS method in error string?

Tags: xcode, selector, nsthread

I've got the common-seeming error for beginning thread programmers, ".. does not implement selector.." except that it lists a CLASS method, not an instance method.  Which makes perfect sense it's defined as an instance method..  Code:

main app delegate header:

```
@interface LSSampleAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSWindow *window;
    LSDataObject labelOptions;
}
-(void) doPrintDisc: (LSDataObject*) labelOptions;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
//-(void) userDidClickStop:(id)sender;
@end
```

thread function first line (in delegate object):

```
-(void) doPrintDisc: (LSDataObject*) labelOptions {
```

thread launch code:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(doPrintDisc:)
    toTarget: [self class]
    withObject: labelOptions];
```

The error:

```
*** -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** +[LSSampleAppDelegate doPrintDisc:])
```

I know, the printDisc method should probably go in the labelOptions object and not the delegate - but I want to get this working before I make another modification..  I've had enough problem today with a malloc error of some kind that seems to show up, only to go away with no apparent reason (it says it's out of memory, but I seriously doubt that it really is unless the lightscribe library itself has a limit on its memory zone) - I assume that the library may run out of memory and then perhaps reset and then the error goes away for a while.

The really odd thing is - earlier today I think I *had* the thread code actually working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(doPrintDisc:)
toTarget: self
withObject: labelOptions];
```

instead.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I found when I thought about what [self class] was actually asking ('give me a selector from AppDelegate', which doesn't exist).  Now I've got it saying **bold**sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all**bold**.  It was giving me a BAD_ACCESS (whatever the kernel error is) in the detachNewThreadSelector call, but that stopped - for some reason.  I think that was changing something about how I allocated the parameter (with new, not retained or autoreleased - memory leak but I'll get this working and then worry about where to put the free).

Comment: Stack trace (where in gdb) gives:

Comment: You'll have to provide more details of the latest error you are encountering and relevant source code if you want any further help. It's not possible to discern from the current description provided.